# Nested forms using build on the association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

Is it a good practice to use build method in a form?

```
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
```

I used this method in my application, it is working fine, but it also displaying in the view a empty result of what the form will create. This is probably because I have the form and display the records saved in the db in the same view. How can I avoid this?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your approach is that after submitting the form with validation errors, when the form is displayed again the values will be reinitialized, so there will be no values or error messages in the form.

If you have a default scaffold controller, put this in the `new` action

```
@comment = @post.comments.build
```

And change the `form_for` call to

```
form_for([@post, @comment]) do |f|
```

This way, the form will always be populated with the submitted `Comment`.

Comment: I don't have a `new action`, because I have the `form` for creating the `comments` in the `post-show page`. And I don't want to create one, is there any other solution? I had a solution which worked but my resources were not nested at that time.

Comment: Then put the `@comment = @post.comments.build` line in your post/show action.